# What deos $\mathbb{C}I$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I've come across this expression
$$
\mathbb{C}I
$$
while studying operators algebras, $C^*$-algebras and AF-algebras, concretely.

- In Kenneth R. Davidson's book $\boldsymbol{C^*}$**-algebras by
  example** page 76, example III.2.3.

  Consider the $C^*$-algebra $\mathbb{C}I+\mathscr{k}\ldots$
- In Bruce Blackadar's book **Operator algebras** page 102, proposition
  II.6.1.8 about representation of $C^*$-algebra $A$

  (ii) $\pi(A)' = \mathbb{C}I$

Can anybody tell me, what $\mathbb{C}I$ in this context means? I could not find the meaning in Davidson's book. Blackadar list only $\mathbb{C}G$ where $G$ is a group and $\mathbb{C}G$ denotes *group algebra*.

I assume $\mathbb{C}$ means complex numbers as always and $I$ might stand for the identity element. Then $\mathbb{C}I$ might stand for all multiples of the identity with each $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,
$$
\mathbb C\,I=\{\lambda\,I:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}.
$$
It is coherent with the notation
$$
AB=\{ab:\ a\in A,\ b\in B\},
$$
and with 
$$
A+B=\{a+b:\ a\in A,\ b\in B\},
$$
etc.